# multiple jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I have looked through other posts, which has been marked as correct - and are the same as what I ave been trying. BUT for some reason I cannot get more than one instance of datepicker to work on my pages. Could anyone think of a reason why as there is no problems in the error console.

```
$('.hasDatepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({autoSize: true,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}); // new doesn't work
});

$('#notedate').datepicker({autoSize: true,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}); // original - works
```

and the HTML

```
<input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="inputText hasDatepicker">
```

Comment: i believe naveen just answered your question :)

Comment: See above edit for html....................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>No need to give `.each`. This should work</strike>

```
$('.hasDatepicker').datepicker({autoSize: true,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}); // wont work :)
```

The above code wont work because hasDatepicker is a class that jQuery UI automatically assigns the inputs.

Please change the class name to something like

```
$('.dp').datepicker({autoSize: true,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}); // will work :)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PaGmj/

Comment: nothing lets me add it as a datepicker, whether I try to assign it directly by a single id or by the class or using each with the class.

Comment: hold on lemme check. i am using it in one of my sites.

Comment: its really confusing as i'm positive your code is correct as it is how I would normally use it.

Comment: aha.. I had tried it with directly using the id - which still wouldn't work because as you say - I had coded that reserved class name in which seemed to mess it all up. Changed the hard coded class name as suggested and its working. Too frustrating when you know the jQuery is correct and still doesn't work.

Comment: happens all the time for me in every language i code at :) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

check it out my 
[Test result](http://jsfiddle.net/KHkEW/). It's about your name class. You just change your class naming.